# is there a possibility of using google maps v1?

Tags: android

I'm at the end to finish an android application,and I want to use v1 google maps, but I see that the site will not open to get the key! 
and thank you for your answer

Comment: Nope, you cannot generate the api key for V1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keys for Maps V1 have not been available for ~18 months. You will need to convert your app to some other mapping solution (Maps V2, OpenStreetMap, etc.) for a production release.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, thus I tried to make that and when I lunch that on an emulator I receive that : "This app won't run without Google Play Services, which are missing from your phone". I see a button "Get Google Play Services". When I click on it, the app stops.

Comment: @user3714770: I have had little luck using Maps V2 on an emulator. If you are "at the end to finish an android application", then you must already have Android hardware, so I suggest that you stick with that for your development. There are various Stack Overflow questions and answers floating about regarding Maps V2 on the emulator, if you wish to continue pursuing that approach.